# Visual Studio loses password for Azure Website Publish

Tags: visual-studio, azure, publish

I am new to publishing to Azure websites straight from Visual Studio.  I am running VS 2015, have setup my Azure website with 1 channel so far and have successfully published to the website.  I then, went about my week (several reboots) and finally came back to the project, made some changes then tried to publish with the saved publish settings.  *The password was missing!*  And, as you know, it is not really a password but rather the hash of the password.

How do you save this information so you are not forced to build a new publish every time you restart Visual Studio?  I now have a half dozen publish profiles, all for the one site!

Comment: do you save the XML file that you're given to publish that contains all of that information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you are signed in with your azure account by entering your credentials every so often.

If you are signed in, try not changing or clicking on the password field. Just click on publish without touching the previous info.

I always either import the XML from Azure Web portal, or I select the website by signing into Azure in Visual Studio.

Please let me know if this helped.

Comment: This didn't work, password is required no matter what. Se my answer.

Answer (score 2):

- In your publish profile, next to Resource Group, click "Manage in
  Cloud Explorer".
- In Cloud Explorer, navigate to your App Service.
- In the bottom window, click "Download Publish Profile".
- In this file you can find your password.